# SSIS with Azure Feature pack - export to parquet with snappy compression

Tags: ssis, compression, parquet

I can see that I can create/upload parquet files on on premise ssis with Azure Feature pack to my azure storage account.

However there is a lack of settings for parquet files, like partition or compression settings.  The last one only available for text files.

what are my options to put a snappy compressed parquet file on my storage without databricks, just from my on premise ssis to storage account.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and you are correct, this is not supported yet.

[image]

[image]

You can share your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) here so that the product group can look into this.
Alternately, here are some helpful [docs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5756/zip-and-unzip-files-using-7zip-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/) you can pursue. Or perform compression on files in SSIS using the ZipFile Class in the recent version of the .NET framework.